# Regex to Match Whole Word or Phrase

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have the following input:

`Hewlett Packard LaserJet Printer Thingy`

I need the following output:

`LaserJet Printer Thingy`

Based on `Hewlett Packard` being matched.

I believe this is a perfect candidate for Regex (I may be wrong) which, unfortunately, I have limited experience of, but a series of string splitting and joining seems verbose.

**What I've Tried**

```
return Regex.Replace(FullProductName, "\b" + ManufacturerName + "\b", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I found out this doesn't work because of `\b` referring to word boundaries, but here I have a phrase.

NOTE: It may sometimes be `Sony` or other one-word manufacturer names.

Comment: did you want to remove the manufacturer name? How regex know which one is the product name and which one is a manufacturer name?

Comment: Wait.... It looks like you have couple of manufacturer names and all you want to do - is remove manufacturer name from product name. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But please assume that a manufacturer name may be small enough to be included in another word. For example, if I have "hell" as the manufacturer and "hell hello", I have a problem with just an ordinary string.replace usage.

Comment: You may try replacing `\b` with `[ ]` or `\ ` or `\s` (last one amtching tabs too) instead of \b which should allow a space in your match.

Comment: You mean this http://regex101.com/r/bY1yT2/5 ? Is that the manufactures name always appears at the first?

Comment: It sounds like string.Replace may be the better solution. For simple stuff like this string.Replace typically performs better than regex and is easier to use.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - that's spot on.

Comment: Isn't this as simple as checking if `String.StartsWith(manufacturer)`, then `string.Remove(0,manufacturer.Length)` ?

Comment: @DeeMac string.Replace wouldn't require any splits or joins if you simply want to remove the first part of the string. You can simply call "Hewlett Packard LaserJet Printer Thingy".Replace("Hewlett Packard", ""). The one draw back is you would need to do that for every manufacture. But you do not need to split and join the string.

Comment: @DeeMac It's all good, we all do that at times. My personal opinion is that for simple things like this using the built in string methods is usually the simpler solution. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a Regex. Just `StartsWith` and `Remove` is enough.

```
string text = "Hewlett Packard LaserJet Printer Thingy";
string manufacturer = "Hewlett Packard";
if(text.StartsWith(manufacturer))
{
    var product =  text.Remove(0, manufacturer.Length).TrimStart();
    //TrimStart used for trimming leading spaces
}
```

Comment: This will work only if the manufacturer is known. What if the manufacturer is 'Sony' or others as OP has mentioned in the question?

Comment: @sgk OP itself uses `ManufacturerName` in his Regex which means he knows the product name upfront. Fine, then my question is how do we know what is the manufacturer? It could be `Sony` or `Sony Ericsson`. What is the algorithm to find the manufacturer? If you answer this question I'll update my answer.

Comment: that’s my whole point, there is no way to make this work for all manufacturers unless there is a complete list of manufacturers.

Comment: Thanks very much @SriramSakthivel. I was over-thinking this problem. This is spot on. I'm not sure I understand what you mean here sgk.

Comment: @DeeMac Let’s say you get the full device name (manufacturer name + device name) from the device directly or some other source, there is no way to remove the manufacture name from the full name unless you compare it with a full list of manufacturers. But if you know the manufacturer name upfront, then certainly the above answer will work. Or more simply you can even use `string deviceName = fullName.Replace(manufacturerName, string.Empty)`

Comment: @sgk OP has already mentioned problem with `String.Replace` in this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017889/regex-to-match-whole-word-or-phrase/26018138?noredirect=1#comment40750195_26017889)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the below regex to match the manufacturer name `Hewlett Packard` or any other single word manufacturer names at the start. Replacing the matched strings with an empty string will give you the desired output.

Regex:

```
^(Hewlett Packard\s*|[A-Z][a-z]+\s*)
```

Replacement string:

```
Empty string
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bY1yT2/6)

**Code:**

```
string str = @"Hewlett Packard LaserJet Printer Thingy
Sony LaserJet Printer Thingy";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?m)^(Hewlett Packard\s*|[A-Z][a-z]+\s*)", "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/iXxLRl)

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it's taught me a bit about Regex already. Unfortunately, I was massively over thinking this. So the other answer is probably most appropriate.